# Why do we only need getStaticPaths() when we use getStaticProps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

If we have a dynamic route

[id].js

```
function id() {
  return <h1>Hello World</h1>
}
export default id
```

and we build the static pages with npm run build, the result is the [id].html page. Any route with /something will work and displays *Hello World*.

But if we generate the content of the page dynamically by using the return value of getStaticProps()
in the component:

```
function id(props) {
  const { test } = props
  return <h1>{test.foo}</h1>
}
export default id
```

Then we need getStaticPaths() again to specify the possible routes.

Why do we only need getStaticPaths() when we use getStaticProps?

Comment: `getStaticPaths` is used at build to generate all pages specified in the function - no other pages will be generated. `getStaticProps` is used at build and dev to set the props for the page. A page will work in dev, but if it's not specified in `getStaticPaths,` it won't get built when statically generating the site.

Comment: then why does it work perfectly if i use dynamic urls with no props?

Comment: If your page doesn't use props - you don't need to set props. To better understand, you can run an experiment by building your site with `npm run build`. Then look in the `out` folder to see what pages were statically generated.

Answer (score 1):

The [nextjs docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-paths) put it simply:

> If a page has Dynamic Routes and uses getStaticProps, it needs to define a list of paths to be statically generated.

**getStaticPaths is required for dynamic SSG pages** because that how Vercel decided to make it.

---

If you want to use `getStaticProps` while maintaining the behavior of not requiring predefined routes from `getStaticPaths`, you can use [fallback: true](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-paths#fallback-true) to tell nextjs to render routes even if they are not predefined by `getStaticPaths`.

You can send an empty array of `paths` and set `fallback: true`:

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const paths = [];
  return { paths, fallback: true };
}
```

This will result in all routes still being accessible, like the behavior from the first part of your question. Here's a full example on codesandbox. In the example, try going to `/test/any-route-you-want` and note that the route will still be rendered: [image: Edit blissful-dan-40qkvq]